# How to find time taken to finish running based on given distance and body mass?

Tags: forces

I would like to find the time taken for a person to finish running 100 m distance based on their body weight(let say 55 kg for now). The possible equation that can be used in order to find the time taken is:
                 F=ma  &    d=vt + (at^2)/2 (might be used)

However, I can't think of how to derive the F=ma equation so that it is possible to find a person finish running time based on their body weight.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you think the finish time is a unique function of body mass?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to find an equation that reliably predicts how long it would take a person to run $100m$ based on body mass. There is very little correlation between body mass and sprinting time. An unfit person of one mass will take significantly longer to finish than a very fit person of the same or lighter (or heavier, for that matter) mass.

The problem with your assumption is that running is not a constant acceleration problem. Nor is it a constant force problem. The amount of acceleration that a runner experiences changes continuously through the cycle of each step. Furthermore, the amount of force available to a runner is a function of the fitness of their muscles, not of body mass alone. I know people around $55kg$ that can run $100m$ in $15s$ and others that would take half a minute or more.

Long story short, you aren't going to find any kind of reasonable or useful equation that takes in body mass and spits out how fast someone can run $100m$. That is, unless (if you know your statistics) you're willing to accept an $R^2$ value of around $10^{-3}$.